# How can I convert string value to object property name

Tags: c#, .net, string, reflection

this is my first time having to do something like this in C#/.NET and somewhat reminds me of what can easily be done in JavaScript using the eval() function or dynamically scripting and generating HTML. I have a string that is taken from user input, lets say `string input = "foo"`. Now I would like to use the value `"foo"` as the name of the property for an object I have, say `cover` in such a way:

```
string input = "foo";
//magic to convert string value to be used
//as a object property name goes here maybe...
var success = cover.foo;
```

Is there a way in C# that I can do such a thing? Possibly using reflection? I've tried but I always am returned with an object that doesn't really solve my problem.

Comment: To do this can be used .Net Reflection.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19911/Dynamically-Invoke-A-Method-Given-Strings-with-Met

Comment: Roughly `var success = cover.GetType().GetProperty(input).GetValue(cover)`, although you probably want the version of `GetProperty` that accepts the expected return type, etc., and you should be careful with exceptions and error cases too.

Comment: It's possible using reflection/dynamic objects, but it might also be useful to try and understand what you are trying to do - there may be alternatives

Comment: I suggest using a switch case. Reflection might sound like the right tool but remember that it is costly. And besides, are you sure you want to use a "string that is taken from user input" and use it to get the property of an object? What if he enters _fooo_ instead of _foo_.

Comment: you want to change the properties names at runtime?

Comment: Not quite, I wanted to change the value of a property SPECIFIED at runtime.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Reflection is the right tool:

```
PropertyInfo pinfo = typeof(YourType).GetProperty("YourProperty");
object value = pinfo.GetValue(YourInstantiatedObject, null);
```

Comment: Thank you, this works and is similar to what was suggested in the comments above with a little tweaking:               `var success = cover.GetType().GetProperty(input).GetValue(cover, null);`