# dotnet .net core 2 OrderBy/OrderByDescending with generic parameter

Tags: c#, .net, sorting

I want create a dynamic way to return a sorted list by parameter xy. The list can be sorted descending, ascending, by id, username, mail and a lot of more.

I receive this parameter as string. So for example `sort=-username`

The minus says that the list descending. And the sort parameter is username.

So I return `user.OrderByDescending(o => o.Username).ToList();`

At the moment with help of a long if-else construct I detect which sorting is needed.

My hope is that I can replace the sort string parameter with help of a function to the object parameter.

Pseudocode

```
//input for example: sort=-username
Boolean isAscending = isAscending(sort) //return true or false
var parameter = isSortStringInsideObject(sort) //
if (isAscending) {
   user.OrderBy(o => o.parameter).ToList();
} else {
   user.OrderByDescending(o => o.parameter).ToList();
}
```

So parameter can be every parameter in object.

I'm new in .net core. So I hope I doesn't formulated an utopian requirement.

Comment: reflection might be helpful here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19276588/1462295

Comment: you could use reflection in some way, but to be honest, unless there are really alot of different properties, you are better just using a big switch statement

Comment: You may have already tried this, but have you considered including the System.Linq.Dynamic library to your project? That would allow you to do dynamic (string based) sorts

Answer (score 5):

Something like this should do the trick (using reflection):

```
var isAscending = GetIsAscending(sort);
var pi = typeof(User).GetProperty(parameter);
if (pi != null)
    user = isAscending
        ? user.OrderBy(a => pi.GetValue(a, null))
        : user.OrderByDescending(a => pi.GetValue(a, null));
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting.. it may be also relevant to use System.Linq.Expression namespace to dynamically create a func passed to Order or OrderByDescending, especially if many possible sort parameters are expected.

E.g. after we have a string parameter

```
var parameter = isSortStringInsideObject(sort)
```

it is possible to construct a function like this (T is the type for the user):

```
Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().ToDictionary(pi => pi.Name);
ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
Expression expression = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameterExpression, properties[parameter]);
Func<T, string> orderFunc = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(expression, parameterExpression).Compile();
```

Looks a little bit heavy :) but it may be effective.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to keep it typed and use a map with strings to funcs so you can lookup the value coming in and map it.

```
var list = new List<Item> { new Item() { Name = "aob", Age = 11 }, new Item() {Name = "bob", Age = 10},};
var input = "-name";

var map = new Dictionary<string, Func<Item, object>>()
{
    {"name", x => x.Name},
    {"age", x => x.Age}
};

if (input.StartsWith('-'))
{
    var orderby = map[input.Substring(1)];
    var orderedEnumerable = list.OrderByDescending(orderby);
}
else
{
    var orderby = map[input];
    var orderedEnumerable = list.OrderBy(orderby);
}
```