# Creating a class dynamically at compile time using other variables/props

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am making a "translator" class, for properties of other entities(classes). This class is going to be used at many places, and can really be decided (hard-coded) before the compile time. How can this process be automated?

For example, 
These are the entity classes

```
public class Teacher
{
 public int Id {get;set;}
 public string Name {get; set;} //Lorem
 public List<Student> Students {get; set;}
 public Teacher() => Students = new List<Student>();
}

public class Student
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public int Name {get; set;}  //Ipsum
  public string Cls {get; set;} // will store grade/class/standard the student is in, in this case class 10
}
```

This is how they were used when there was no translation:

```
var k = string.Format("Teacher {0} has tought student {1} who is in class {2}.",teacher.Name, teacher.Students[0].Name, teacher.Students[1].Cls)
```

Sample output for this is:

> Teacher Lorem has taught student Ipsum who is in class 10.

The translator class that is generated looks like:

```
public class Translator
{
 public int Id {get; set;}
 public string Teacher_Id {get; set;} // doesn't matter
 public string Teacher_Name {get; set;} //teacher or mentor
 public string Teacher_Student {get; set;} //student or mentored
 public string Student_Id {get; set;} //doesn't matter
 public string Student_Name {get; set;} // student or menties
 public string Student_Cls {get; set;}  // class or standard
}
```

And the code for translating the string would look like:

```
var k = string.Format("{3} {0} has {4} {5} {1} who is in {6} {2}.",teacher.Name, teacher.Students[0].Name, teacher.Students[1].Cls, translator.Teacher_Name, translator.Teacher_Student, translator.Student_Name, translator.Student_Cls)
```

Different regions/schools have different conventions for classes and teachers.

> 1. Teacher Lorem has taught student Ipsum who is in class 10.
> 2. Mentor Lorem has mentored mentee Ipsum who is in standard 10.

I have a list of all the variable names that are going to be there is the translator class (in a ICollection or json), only trouble is creating it at the compile time.

I would really like to know if this is possible to this way, and if there are other better approaches to this. We are using Vue for frontend and giving users the option to create/customize their own language. I have an alternate approach, I just think if this is possible to do, then it would be much faster and cleaner.

Comment: Can the `Translator` properties just return the `Class1` and `Class2` variables?

Comment: Or are you looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19276475/how-can-i-convert-string-value-to-object-property-name)?

Comment: @Greg, yes they can but I don't see how you can use that. translator.Class1_Name is going to return "Name" when translator is engilsh and "nombre" when it is spanish

Comment: I think you need to update your question to include that information (and expand on what the translator will do).  That's not clear from the question.  I'd include an example as well.

Comment: did you try reflexion :  foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in YourClass.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    var valueProp = propertyInfo.GetValue(YourClass, null);

Comment: Reflection is runtime right? So everytime the program is strated it is doing to do this work, correct? I think that would slow the program, and is not really what I am looking for.

Comment: Looking up a few properties at startup isn't going to noticeably slow your program down. Also, are you sure you want to do this? Why don't you use the de facto translation mechanism provided by .NET, being resource files?

Comment: @CodeCaster, not really looking for a proper translation system as you can see in the spanish translation. Also, translation is not the only place this can be applied. If possible, we could use this to create methods too at the compile time like Class2.UpperCase**Property** and Class1.UpperCase**Name** (thought of this example on go...)

Comment: Property and method names are things to compile against. Strings are things you display. Why not use a `Dictionary<string, string>`? What use is it renaming a property, if your code can't compile against it anyway?

Comment: I've read this question 5 times and I still can't figure out what in the world you're attempting to do. Please provide a more real-world example. I think the use of generic names like `Class1`, `Class2`, `Property`, etc. is obscuring your goals.

Comment: @CodeCaster what do you mean by compile against? Also, if you are familiar with linq, then `table.select(s=>s.Id== id )` is something that we use there a lot. This can be really simplified to `table.selectId(id)` is there are functions like these. Not only for id, for every other property of that entity.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm with @Chris on this. It's not clear to me what problem you're trying to solve. If you rename a property at compile time, other code doesn't know about this rename and cannot use that property, do you understand that? So renaming the property doesn't seem to solve any useful problem.

Comment: @ChrisPratt updated the question. Sorry if it was not clear.

Comment: Okay. I think I understand, but your approach here is bonkers in that case, which is probably why there was so much confusion in the first place. You don't need a "translator" class. Everything you need is already built in to ASP.NET Core. Checkout https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2. You just need to provide localizations for the text in general. It supports string interpolation, so you just specify the resource and pass in the values, and the right text spits out depending on the user's culture.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, I would have loved to go with that as CodeCaster and others too have suggested. We are using Vue for frontend, and we are giving option to user to customize/create their own language (proper UI no xml/json etc.). Moreover this is kind of a task for me, and I have come up with an alternative solution, but still wanted to know if this is possible or not? I think I should mention this in question too.